# Get latitude/longitude values at center of each grid cell

Tags: r, r-sf

How do I create a grid that includes the latitude and longitude values at the center of each cell? I have used st_make_grid to create a grid within my bounding box, but is there a way with this method or an alternative one to extract the latitude and longitude values?

Comment: You can use `st_coordinates(st_centroid(<your grid>))` to get the coordinates of each cell

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to get the values in decimal degrees?

Comment: Try `st_coordinates(st_transform(st_centroid(<your grid>), 4326)))`